# Co-worker won't understand that we don't put compiled binaries into git

Tags: communication

He has no idea, what is `.gitignore`. He has no interest to even hear it, if I try to explain it to him. Probably he thinks roughly this:

> "I only want to make the work done"

And yes, this is what he is doing; although he does not communicate it clearly.

It is a simple single-person project for him, before he is going to an external customer into an outsourcing project.

If I take this problem to the management, the management will see me, out of this project, and him, working on this project. Obviously this is not the case if I should criticize his work.

His agressive idiotism is clearly visible, however if I see myself with his eyes, probably he thinks the same from me.

After he goes away, probably my task will be to handle the s..t what he left; and the view of the management will be this:

> X could make the task nearly done, why @GraySheep can't make it ready?

What could I do?

<sub>(It is not the first similar in this job, but a pattern. But... also I am not flawless. Would it be an option to run away?)</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112905/discussion-on-question-by-gray-sheep-co-worker-wont-understand-that-we-dont-pu).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What could I do?

As you are not his superior, this is not your project, or problem, or responsibility and the issue is not actually an issue but more of an annoyance (if it was something mission critical that would be a whole other topic) then there is nothing more for you to do than to recommend him some best practices and maybe document your efforts so you can bring those up if it ever becomes any of the above list.

Until then stop looking for a fight and focus on your own work.

Comment: The second part of the question is, that it will be likely my task to "make it ready", what will first mean a huge cleanup; what will likely mean that I will make far lesser visible features in the same time, than he did.

Comment: @GraySheep then document what mess he is making and then make your cleanup visible. If this purity actually brings value it shouldn't be hard to show to the product people after. Something like saying "I removed the binaries so, as a result, I now develop the application 50% faster".

Comment: Yes. But again the slow co-worker will criticize the fast. I am starting to think that maybe it is not really so bad if there are some binaries in a git repo.

Comment: @GraySheep sounds like you have bigger issues than repo sanity in there, and this is barely some surface. Maybe worth a different question here, or maybe at /interpersonal.

Comment: Right, thanks. I already know, what to do. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't force someone who doesn't report to you to do anything.

However your team should have some standards and procedures. Often these are unwritten or written and outdated, and everyone does their own thing. That results in resentment and confusion. Either you're constantly competing to change things to your liking, or trying to work out how things work in each particular area. Eventually you end up with a legacy system, where everyone is afraid to touch anything.

You should ask your boss if you have any standards, and if the team can spent a bit of time discussing them. Make a list, and discuss whether each is important enough to have a rule, then decide what you all prefer and vote if necessary.

Assuming your team agrees that putting binaries in git is a bad idea, it's a lot easier to ask someone to follow a team standard than your personal one. If anyone refuses to follow the standard, it becomes your boss' problem, not yours.

Comment: Thanks - although I've chosen to remain silent until it does not directly conflict my work tasks. For example, if I get "just do X in the project", then I first will mention that I need to cleanup the git repo.